# Regular expression to replace < within <TR><TD> with some special character

Tags: php, domdocument

I have string like

```html
<td align='left'style='font-family: Courier New;'>
 Therapeutic target for gout patients: <6.0 mg/dL
</td>
<td class='tableCell'>
 < OR = 30
</td>
```

Hear is my code for this

```
$string  = preg_replace('/:( *<)/', " &lt; ", $string);
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Hide warnings
$DOM->loadHTML($string);
$rows = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) 
{
    echo "<HR/>";
    $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName('td');
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols->length; $j++) 
    {
        echo "<br/>".$cols->item($j)->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

First <td> is showing "Therapeutic target for gout patients < 6.0 mg/dL" and second is showing blank. can any one tell me some expression which helps me to fetch both data.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` to extract required data and here we are using `regex` to convert `<` to `&lt;`.

**Regex:** `/<(?=[\d\s])/`

> **1.** `<(?=[\d\s])` match `<` and positive lookahead for `space` or `digit`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/789539)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$string='<td align="left" style="font-family: Courier New;">
    Therapeutic target for gout patients: <6.0 mg/dL
</td> 
<td class="tableCell">
    < OR = 30
</td>';
$string  = preg_replace('/<(?=[\d\s])/', " &lt; ", $string);
$domDocument= new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);
$domDocument->encoding="utf-8";
foreach($domDocument->getElementsByTagName("td") as $value)
{
    echo $value->textContent;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

`Therapeutic target for gout patients:  < 6.0 mg/dL
 <  OR = 30`

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit more brutal regex than the one Sahil Gulati used.

```
$string  = preg_replace('/[<](?=[^>]+[<])/', "&lt;", $string);
```

It looks for < that are followed by a < instead of a >
So it ignores the < that are part of a tag.